# Getting DLCs from US for Destiny which was bought in Canada

Tags: ps4, destiny

I bought Destiny in the Canadian Store. But I have credit in my U.S account. If I buy the dlc's on the American store, will they work on the base game bought in the Canadian Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the dlc that you bought from the American store will work on your Canadian account, but you have to keep the American account open at all times to be able to access it.

I hope this helped. Good luck Guardian.

Comment: What do you mean keep the American account open at all times? Like, enter daily or something? thanks man!

Comment: @Zarathustrax he means do not delete your American PSN account.

Comment: @Dupree3 Oh, ok. Perfect.